# Windows 10 Installation power off loop

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I'm trying to install Windows 10 from scratch on an old Dell machine for testing purposes. The machine meets the minimum Windows 10 specs.

I've tried creating a grub boot USB from Ubuntu Linux. The machine boots from USB, I can select the Windows I want to install (Windows 32 bit). I then see a loading files screen. When the loading files progress bar reaches the end, the machine reboots and I am stuck in that loop.

I've also tried a different installation medium - DVD from a different Windows Image - the 90 day Windows Enterprise evaluation available from MSDN (again, 32-bit version). The machine boots from the DVD drive, all the while showing the Windows logo. After about a minute the machine reboots and asks to boot from DVD again i.e a similar loop.

The only hard drive attached is a Linux formatted drive which has Ubuntu 15.04 installed on it. I plan to wipe that drive.

Its an older Dell machine which has a 3Ghz Intel CPU (p4 with HT) and 2GB Ram. It has a BIOS, not UEFI. I'm not expecting any kind of performance, I just want a test bed machine. I'm not interested in a virtualised install.

I do not believe this is related to a Win10 reboot issue which existing users saw after an update.

CPUInfo:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 3
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x17
cpu MHz     : 2992.539
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl cid xtpr
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5985.07
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Do you have a windows box around? I got it running fine with the official tool to make an install usb, and that would rule out the grub boot usb being the issue.

Comment: I could borrow one but it seems weird that I'm getting the power cycle using two different install mediums. I guess I could also create the boot image from a VM. Also, you may be using much better hardware.

Comment: Oh, I missed that you used a DVD. Wierd. hmm. What CPU is it, exactly?

Comment: I dont know anything more than I already put in the question I'm afraid :( Pentium 4 with hyperthreading (tried disabling that in the BIOS, same result)

Comment: I know win 10 has some specific processor instructions it needs. Maybe the output of cat /proc/sysinfo from a Linux livedisk would be useful there.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek is there a way to run the installer in some kind of verbose mode?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I typically end up trying multiple methods till one works. Typically upgrades from USB key work best for me, except when it dosen't.

Comment: AFAIK W10 doesnt work on platforms previous to LGA775, that being true this system *isn't* compatible.

Comment: It is an LGA775. Wouldn't I get some kind of error rather than the machine just rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 requires that your processor has PAE, SSE2 and NX support working and enabled.

Your `/proc/cpuinfo` output shows NX is missing. Either your processor is not capable of running Windows 10, or the above feature have been switched off in BIOS.

[Edit]

The information suggests the processor is of the Intel Pentium 4 53x series. Three of the 5 models do not have NX capability, the two remaining do.

[Edit 2]

Your CPUID string (0f34h) points to one of three possible SKUs, all three do *not* have NX capability.

Comment: Thanks. Where did you get 0f34h from?

Comment: Family 13, model 3, stepping 4 in hex is 0f34: http://world.std.com/~swmcd/steven/tech/cpu.html